# Different design time/Runtime WinForms control behaviour

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio

I am building an app that uses some built in and some 3rd party controls (DevExpress).

Inside the designer, everything looks OK, however while running the app, some controls are placed wrong.

Are there any easy ways to debug this issue?

More specifically, i have a container that holds 2 controls in it.
These controls should stack nicely together one on top of the other (indeed it looks like that in the Designer).

While running the app, one control is displayed on top of the other blocking it (see attached image).
[image]

Another weird thing is that some properties of the 2 controls that get overlapped are not updated with respect to their visual status.

this means that a control has a Location of (0, 300) but in fact appears to be in (0, 0).

Comment: DevExpress bug? Can you show the code?

Comment: Right Click on the controls in the IDE and reset the ordering, WinForms controls get rendered in the order they are initiated in in the Code Behind file unless a specific order is set.

Comment: Very strange behaviour instead. DevExpress is a well established component vendor. Very hard that a bug so big escaped their quality control. Sometime the culprit is more simple. Anchor property? Copy/paste from another form?

Comment: How are you creating controls on your form.. i have not seen such behaviour till now.. put your code that behaving weird..

Comment: This is not a bug in DevExpress, probably some other weird thing going on which i have no idea

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could place the two controls in the two panels of a `SplitContainer` and dock (fill) them there. This has also the advantage that the users can resize the controls.

Another alternative is the `TableLayoutPanel`.